# Saturating BJT on different value than 10

Tags: transistors, bjt

Is it possible to saturate BJT 2n2222 at beta value different from 10 to 37.5?

this is why 10 to 37.5:
[image]

```
when Ic=1.0mA   ->    beta = 1m/0.1m       = 10
when Ic=10mA    ->    beta = 10m/1m        = 10
when Ic=150mA   ->    beta(min) = 150m/15m = 10
                      beta(max) = 150m/4m  = 37.5
when Ic=500mA   ->    beta = 500m/~50      = ~10
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem -- what are you trying to achieve as your end-goal? In saturation, the effective current gain is not determined by the transistor's inherent beta (a result of temperature/process variation) but mostly by the external circuit. Beta is more directly applicable in forward-active mode

Comment: take the 10mA curve, for example: the vertical trait means active zone, Ib = 0.05mA for Ic = 10mA, for a beta of 200. It all boils down to where you consider saturation to start. Let's say for me the bjt is saturated when Vce goes under 0.1V, then for the same curve it means it's saturated for Ib comprised between 0.1mA and 1mA, corresponding to beta forced between 100 and 10. So, when does saturation start for you?

Comment: on the 10mA curve, doesnt the saturation is more stable\promised when Ib close to 1mA? regarding to my circuit, Ib is limited to 16mA (connected to RPI) and the load require Ic = 300mA

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:
**Yes** ...saturation can be reached at higher \$HFE_{forced}\$ than ten.

However, it is risky. Risky because HFE varies:

- from transistor-to-transistor
- with temperature
- with current magnitude flowing through collector-emitter.

[image: HFE for PN2222 from data sheet]

Current gain in the table above is specified @ 25 degrees C. Note that at high currents, the measured gain is done with a pulse test to avoid heating the chip.
A designer might survey this table and see that *worst-case* current gain is only 35. It is even lower if saturation current is above 500mA, especially if the transistor runs hot (which is very likely).

The data sheet graphs (below) showing saturation region are taken with a "nominal" transistor, whose HFE is quite high, certainly much higher than *worst-case*. Perhaps 150-200.
Should you happen to apply these graphs to a transistor whose HFE is near minimum (like 35), then saturation can very easily be missed, the consequences being failure due to overheating. The circuit function may fail due to collector-to-emitter voltage being too large.
[image: saturation region PN2222 transistor]

from ON semiconductor data sheet: [http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Datasheets/PN2222-D.pdf](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/Datasheets/PN2222-D.pdf)

 So if you happen to select a nicely-high HFE PN2222A transistor (like HFE=200) then you only need to supply 0.1mA base current to saturate it when driving a 10mA collector or emitter load current. For such a transistor, the rule-of-thumb overdrive **factor-of-10** is overkill.
But woe be to you if HFE is lower, or temperature drops to -55C.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer :)  the transistor considered to be stable saturated at (the third curve for example ) Ib=0.86m and Ic=0.15?

Comment: Not saturated with 0.86mA base current. That sample transistor requires more than 1.5mA base current to reach saturation. At 1.5mA base current, it is assumed that 0.15A collector current flows. \$V_{CE}\$ will be about 0.3V or less. At really low temperature, saturation would not be assured with 1.5mA base current and 0.15A collector current because a low temperature decreases current gain as seen from the top graph. And if you happened to choose a lower-HFE transistor, saturation would not be assured as well.