# A paradox in relay drive circuit

Tags: current, relay, bjt, npn

According to the circuit shown below:

[image]

If we assume a V<sub>be</sub> of 0.7 V for Q1, the base current of Q1 is (5-0.7)/100 = 43 μA, and assuming a β of 100 for Q1, we have a collector current of around 4.3 mA.

But if we look at this from another point of view, for example, we assume a V<sub>be</sub> of -0.7 V for Q2. It means current flowing through the 47 kΩ resistor is 14 μA, plus we have a base current for Q2 which we have to add to the 14 μA to get the collector current for Q1.

But still, the two currents derived so far for the Q1 collector current (4.3 mA and 14 μA) are too different. What is the reason for this?

Comment: The "assuming a beta of 100 for Q1, we have a collector current around 4.3mA" part is wrong. A more correct stance would be "assuming a beta of 100 for Q1, we have a **max** collector current around 4.3mA", but the collecctor current is, anyway, limited by the other parts of the circuit (e.g. the 47k resistor, as you noticed).

Comment: Base current for Q2 is forced to be the difference between the current in R4 and the current in the 47k resistor.

Comment: The 47k resistor is just to ensure Q2 gets turned off, the bulk of the current flows through the EB junction of Q2. There's two current paths, why are you concerned by the difference?

Comment: @dim Thank you that helps.

Comment: @Kartman I know there are two current paths, but their currents combined is way less than the current Q1 can supply. Which dim explained the reason.

Comment: @Momo The base current of \$Q_2\$ can be quite large. And it will be whatever it needs to be so that the sums work out. I can't make heads or tails of your last question. It seems to me that it misses the \$Q_2\$ base current when creating a false conundrum. The current in the \$47\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor will add to the base current from \$Q_2\$ to make exactly the current in the \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor which will be exactly the collector current of \$Q_1\$. The circuit could be better. But that's a different issue.

Comment: @jonk So like, we know Q1 can sink a current of 4.3mA and we also know that the current though 47k resistor is 14uA. Does this mean Q2 base current will be 4.3mA - 14uA = 4.286mA?

Comment: @Momo We don't know those figures. But if you do feel you know them (assume them as fact), then yes that would be the calculation result.

Comment: Please note that because of Q2 Vbe of 0.7V and 1k base resistor, there is about 11.3 mA maximum available via Q2 base. Assuming 200mA relay, and Q2 beta of 100, about 2mA base current is needed so at least 2mA must be sunk by Q1. In real life, betas will not be 100, Vbe won't be exactly 0.7V, and base resistor to MCU would be much lower than 100k.

Comment: Or you could short/eliminate the base resistor, put a 390 Ohm resistor in the emitter leg to ground, and short out the 1k resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The "assuming a beta of 100 for *Q1*, we have a collector current around 4.3mA" part is wrong. A more correct stance would be "assuming a beta of 100 for *Q1*, we have a max collector current around 4.3mA", but the collector current is, anyway, limited by the other parts of the circuit.

Answered by @dim

Comment: But it's not "limited by other parts of the circuit". If Q1 were to be fully on Q2 base current trough R4 would be ~11mA. If Q1 is not driven hard enough to supply this *it* will be what's limiting current.

Comment: @Unimportant I think the base current of *Q2* depends on the collector current of *Q2*. It can have any value. We just need to make sure that Q1 can supply this current plus 47k resistor current. So *Q1* just needs to ensure that it can supply this current, but this doesn't mean that *Q1* will make current independently. I hope I could explain it clearly.

Comment: No, The BE junction of Q2 will act much like a diode. When forward biased it will drop around 0.7V and allow as much current to flow as is available. It does not depend on the collector current at all.

Comment: @Unimportant That's a good point. How did you get *11mA* for base current?

Comment: Assuming Q1 is fully saturated (it won't be with the given values, but assume), it would drop ~0.3V. Q2's BE junction will drop ~0.7V. 12V supply - 0.3V - 0.7V = 11V across R4. 11V / 1K = 11mA. (Ignore the 47K, it's current is insignificant here). In reality, with the given values, Q1 does not have enough base current to be able to supply 11mA collector current, so Q1 will be limiting current in this case (thus, there will be a voltage drop across Q1 CE).

Comment: @Unimportant I think you are right, thank you. Let's try this with real components. Lets' say *Q1* is [BC817][2] *Q2* is BC807[3], and the relay is [Finder 40.61][1].

[1]: https://www.finder-relais.net/en/finder-relays-series-40.pdf
[2]: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc817-40w-d.pdf
[3]: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc807-25w-d.pdf

Comment: @Unimportant The relay needs 53mA. BC807-40's minimum beta is 170. BC817's minimum beta is 40. Collector current of Q2 is 53mA with a minimum beta of 170 we get a base current of 0.3amps. then what happens to that 11mA?

Comment: You're working backwards. Collector current divided by beta does not dictate base current. Base current multiplied by beta dictates **max** collector current. The BE junction will allow all the current to flow that is available, it must be limited externally. So, in the given example with a required collector current of 53mA and a beta of 170 you will need a **minimum** base current of ~0.3mA, but more will flow if you don't limit it externally. Do note that in reality, when used as a power switch, we want our transistors to be saturated. For saturation often a beta of around 10 is used.

Comment: @Unimportant In order to have a base current of 0.3mA I think we need  to have R4 equal to *36.7k*. This means that base current of Q1 has to be at least 7.5uA which means a base resistor of 573k? One other question: how can I choose a beta? I thought beta is dictated by transistor itself?

Comment: Those calculations look correct. However, transistors have large manufacturing tolerances. Beta can vary wildly from part to part (of the same type), with temperature, and other parameters. Therefore one should design with large margins. Since Q2 bears the load we want it to be saturated, so assume a beta of 10 for Q2. Give it ~5mA base current (R4 = 2.2K). Q1 can be more relaxed imho, because it's not driving a large load, and Q2 has large margins to pick up some slack, you can go with the minimum beta of 40 here. So, say, 33K for it's base resistor.

Comment: @Unimportant But 10 is way less than 170 for *Q2*. Can it really get that low?

Comment: It's a rule-of-thumb for saturation. See more here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535848/saturating-bjt-on-different-value-than-10

Comment: @Unimportant Alright, I'll take a look at it. You have been a great help. Thanks for your patient. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> But still, the two currents derived so far for the Q1 collector current (4.3 mA and 14 μA) are too different.

No, they are not.

The base-emitter junction of Q2 is a diode.  The collector load for Q1 is this diode and a resistor in parallel.  There is nothing strange about this.  As the current increases from 0 mA, eventually the current through the resistor (reference designators - ! ) increases until the voltage across it equals the forward voltage of the diode (Vbe).  Per your calculation, this happens at around 15 uA.  Note that at this low current level, a better value for Vbe is 0.6 V, reducing the current at the beginning of conduction to 13 uA.

At this point, assuming a theoretically-perfect diode), the voltage across the resistor never increases, as it is clamped by the diode.  If Q1 is driven to saturation, the maximum current through the diode is limited by R4 and the system power supply voltage.  For your schematic, this is 11.4 mA.  Of that, 13 uA is going through the 47 K resistor, and the rest is going through the diode (the Q2 base-emitter junction).  That is the nature of these components and how they function.

AND - Your circuit will not perform well.  Because Q1 is *not* operating in saturation, its actual collector current will wander all over the place due to variations in temperature, device aging, and the fact that a transistor's gain is not anything close to a constant.  You kept the part number secret, but the datasheet probably has performance plots showing this.

What constitutes "too different"?  What would be an acceptable amount of difference?